# Dojo Form Submit Woes

Tags: forms, zend-framework, dojo, dijit.form

So here's the problem. We have some big dojo forms created using Zend_Dojo_Form. The problem is that validation, while working per element, does not work on any of the submit buttons. Due to the inflexibility of the standard layouts, we're compelled to use viewscripts.

I thought I had the whole thing working fine, that was until I needed to make sure that when you went from page to page of the multipage form using the quick links that it submitted the current page (with validation.)

I noticed that when I force-fired the click event on the submit button, no validation was occurring (or rather, there was no preventing the form submission if there were invalid values. Those values just were not submitted.)

So I looked at some tutorials where I found that the form is validated by calling

```
dijit.byId('form-id').validate();
```

or the shortcut I was looking for, primarily (originally)

```
dijit.byId('form-id').submit();
```

Neither of which are functions, since the byId is returning undefined. What this means is our viewscript - or whatever the whole process is - generating dojo forms with Zend is partly voodoo anyway - does not actually generate the dojo form dijit.

So how does one do this in a viewscript? As in, what sort of php calls or attribs does one attach to the form tag to get it to be interpreted by Dojo to be the basis for a form dijit?

Here is the code from the viewscript:

```
<form action="<?= $this->escape($this->element->getAction()) ?>"
      method="<?= $this->escape($this->element->getMethod()) ?>"
      id="case-record-form">
```

Comment: Are you using the dojo view helper?

Comment: <?php Zend_Dojo::enableView($this); ?> , yes. Plus wrapping the the whole thing in a div with class='nihilo'. I'm sure the fields wouldn't even validate individually without it.

Comment: I just need to know what needs to be called at the beginning of my viewscript to ensure that the form that gets created gets interpreted as defining a dijit... right now it doesn't.

Comment: It seems Zend is somewhere creating a list of zenddijits that are an array that gets parsed using mixin() - what function can I call during my viewscript to ensure that form container itself is added to this list? anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Anyone? This is mission critical.

Comment: I meant the view helper - try `<?=$this->dojo()?>` in your view if it isn't already there. If that doesn't help, could you remove all but one of your form elements and then edit your question to include the HTML output of your form, along with what extra JS you think should be there.

Comment: Seems like it has to do with actually including the DijitForm decorator, but doing so AFTER the viewscript, and not including form tags in the viewscript. This is somewhat undocumented behavior, but it does make sense vis a vis the way the form decorator works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds very similar to a problem I had.  If I rendered the form by echoing it, validation worked, but when using a viewscript it would not.  I discovered that when using a viewscript, Zend does not add the form to its zendDijits array, so you have to do it manually.

Add something like:

```
$script = 'zendDijits.push({"id":"MyFormId","params":{"dojoType":"dijit.form.Form"}})';
$this->headScript()->appendScript($script);
```

at the top of the viewscript.

Comment: One thing I did also was to not put the form in the viewscript and do this: 

`            $this->setDecorators(array(
                array('ViewScript', array('viewScript' => '[form].phtml')),
                  'DijitForm',
            ));`

This caused it to render the viewscript and wrap it in the DijitForm.